# Calculate Discrete Cosine Transformation of Image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to use the OpenCV 2.3 Python wrapper to calculate the DCT for an image. Supposedly, images == numpy arrays == CV matrices, so I thought this should work:

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.dct(img1)
```

However, this throws the error:

```
cv2.error: /usr/local/lib/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp:2247: error: (-215) type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 in function dct
```

I realize the error means the input should be either a 32-bit or 64-bit single-channel floating point matrix. However, I thought that's how my image should have loaded when specifying grayscale, or at least it should be close enough so that CV2 should be able to figure out the conversion.

What's the appropriate way to convert an image for DCT using cv2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any easy way to do this with cv2. The closest solution I could find is:

```
import cv, cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = img1.shape[:2]
vis0 = np.zeros((h,w), np.float32)
vis0[:h, :w] = img1
vis1 = cv2.dct(vis0)
img2 = cv.CreateMat(vis1.shape[0], vis1.shape[1], cv.CV_32FC3)
cv.CvtColor(cv.fromarray(vis1), img2, cv.CV_GRAY2BGR)

cv.SaveImage('output.jpg', img2)
```

Comment: Updated from `cv` to `cv2` (opencv 3+ is without Mat): https://pastebin.com/SFzFrkxd ```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
img1 = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gray.shape[:2]
vis0 = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.float32)
vis0[:h, :w] = gray
vis1 = cv2.dct(vis0)  
#img2 = np.zeros((vis1.shape[0], vis1.shape[1]), dtype=np.float32) ###img2 = cv2.CreateMat(vis1.shape[0], vis1.shape[1], cv.CV_32FC3)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(vis1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I did not want to write this answer but as I seen some answers are voted up while they are wrong, I decided to write.

The `dct` operation works on inputs in any range so I really do not understand why others scaled it to [0, 1]. But in opencv, you need to pass `numpy.float32` numbers.

```py
x = np.array([8, 16, 24 , 32, 40, 48, 56, 64])
cv2.dct(np.float32(x))

# output
array([[ 101.82337189],
       [ -51.53858566],
       [   0.        ],
       [  -5.38763857],
       [   0.        ],
       [  -1.60722351],
       [   0.        ],
       [  -0.40561762]], dtype=float32)
```

But if you scale it, almost all small values will be lost.

Here is a link to formula and examples:
https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node231.html#DCTbasis

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that I got from openCV forums and it worked.

```
img = cv2.imread(fn, 0)      # 1 chan, grayscale!
imf = np.float32(img)/255.0  # float conversion/scale
dst = cv2.dct(imf)           # the dct
img = np.uint8(dst)*255.0    # convert back
```

Comment: I do not understand why you have scaled to [0, 1]. https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node231.html#DCTbasis says clearly that input value could be in any range and when I tried it on 0 to 255, it worked fine rather than 0, 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you load the image as grayscale, it is actually read in at 8-bits per pixel and not as 32-bit float values.

Here is how you would do it:

```
img1_32f = cv.CreateImage( cv.GetSize(img1), cv.IPL_DEPTH_64F, 1)
cv.Scale(img1, img1_32f, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Also, have a look at the [dft.py](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/python/dft.py) example. This should give you a feel for how to use the `dft` as well.

Comment: Thanks. However, I know how to do this using cv. My question was how to do this using cv2. Or is the OpenCV team planning to maintain both cv and cv2 modules indefinitely?

Comment: Also, your example doesn't work with the output from cv2.imread().

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has slice operators for working between arrays of different orders.

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np   

img1 = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg')
# or use cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE 
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('input', img1)
w,h = img1.shape
# make a 32bit float for doing the dct within
img2 = np.zeros((w,h), dtype=np.float32)
print img1.shape, img2.shape
img2 = img2+img1[:w, :h]
dct1 = cv2.dct(img2)
key = -1
while(key < 0):
    cv2.imshow("DCT", dct1)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to do it with scipy:

```
import os.path
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.fftpack import fft, dct

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_counter = 1

    # Apply DCT to the noisy image patches.
    noise_image_path = 'noise_images/' + str(image_counter) + '.png'
    noise_image = Image.open(noise_image_path)         
    noise_dct_data = dct(noise_image)
    print(noise_dct_data)
```